# Can't build dtproj [SSIS] project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

When I try to build a project in Visual Studio 2005 that has a .dtproj file, I get the error message:

Make sure the application for the project type (.dtproj) is installed.

This project was build on another system, but even after installing SQL Server 2005 & and SQL SP3, it still does not build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the Business Intelligence Studio that is a part of the SQL Server Installation.

Comment: It turns out that Visual Studio 2005 comes with SQLExpress, which does not have Business Intelligence Studio. Uninstalling express and then installing the full version was the fix.

Comment: This is also what you need to open dtproj on a VS 2008 installation. +1

Comment: Can this be done without the SQL Server installation media? I've installed SSDT for the current version of VS, and this doesn't seem to have solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing development tools from your installation of SQL Server.

Comment: There's an option when installing SQL Server to install the Visual Studio tools.  Apparently it wasn't selected.

Answer (score 0):

On my workstation at work I have VS.NET 2005, 2008 and 2010 loaded and needed to modify a package created in a 2005 environment.  I only had SQL Server 2008 installed and therefore the BIDS environment for 2008 SSIS development.  I had to go back and get the install for SQL Server 2005 and installed only the Integration Services component (instead of the entire SQL Server 2005 setup) and it resolved the issue mentioned above.